# javax.servlet.FilterChain setting ContentType as text/plain in Firefox

Tags: java, filter, content-type

I'm not 100% clued up on Java, or Filters. Taking over some code and we have discovered that .ZIP (uppercase) files in Firefox are rendered as text/plain. The .ZIP file downloads correctly in IE but not Firefox. A .zip (lowercase) downloads correctly in both IE and Firefox.

As far as I can make out the web.xml points to a Filter class.
At the crux of the code where chain.doFilter is called I've tried to set the content type before the chain.doFilter, and then check what the content type is before and after doFilter.

This is the code:

```
LOG.debug("Current Content Type: " + response.getContentType());
response.setContentType("application/zip");
LOG.debug("New Content Type: " + response.getContentType());

chain.doFilter(request, response);

LOG.debug("Current Content Type2: " + response.getContentType());
```

The output of this is as follows (roughly):

```
Current Content Type: null New Content Type: application/zip

<Some stuff where doFilter is called />

Current Content Type2: text/plain
```

In Firefox I get the content type as text/plain so I think its the doFilter setting the content type.

We don't have the option of changing the extension as these are files coming from an external source so cannot be changed.

Any pointers as to why this happens, or how to get a .ZIP file to prompt to download correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: when you say `chain.doFilter()`, it will call the next filter in `web.xml` defined with same or more specific `url-pattern` and finally it will invoke the actual servlet to process your request, so it's possible that any of your filters in the filter chain or in fact your servlet might setting the content-type in reponse. See your web.xml and you'll understand the request processing flow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `doFilter()` method is calling the next filter in the filter chain.

The filter chain is the list of filters, as they are defined in your web.xml.

So, maybe there is a filter in your web.xml, that does change the content type.

But maybe it is simpler, look for mime mapping either in the default configuration of your application server, or define one in your web.xml and see if that helps:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>ZIP</extension>
    <mime-type>application/zip</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks so much - didn't even know there was a mime-mapping section in the web.xml. Found it and added the new config and it works perfectly now! Much better than trying to fix it in code!